# Python version of R's ifelse statement

Tags: python, r, pandas, if-statement

I am trying to learn Python after learning R and an simple ifelse statement.

In R I have:

```
df$X <- if(df$A == "-1"){-df$X}else{df$X}
```

But I am unsure how to implement it in Python, I have tried:

```
df['X'][df['A'] <1] = -[df['X']
df['X'][df['A'] >1] = [df['X']
```

But this leads to errors, would appreciate some help.

Comment: A tip, *python* is generally not vectorized, so if you are using some sort of vectorization in your R code, you want to look at `numpy`/`pandas` for similar functionality using Python.

Comment: Thanks juanpa.arrivillage

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The equivalent is [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```py
import numpy as np
np.where(df['A'] < 1, -df['X'], df['X'])
```

This checks if the values in column `A` are lower than 1. If so, it returns the corresponding value multiplied by -1 from `df['X']`, otherwise it returns the corresponding value in `df['X']`.

That said, your error/warning is probably raised because of chained indexing. Instead of `df['X'][df['A'] <1]` you should use `df.loc[df['A'] <1, 'X']`. Then you can do the same with two steps as you have shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use list comprehension for doing an equivalent of `ifelse` of R in Python. Showing an example in Python 3, with `l` and `m` as equivalents of `df['A']`  and `df['X']`

```
l = [ 1, 2, -3, -4, -5]
m = [ 10, 20, -30, -40, 50]

k = [ y if x>0 else -y for x,y in list(zip(l,m))]
k
>>> [10, 20, 30, 40, -50]
```

This removes the dependence on `numpy`

In addition, it can also be used for filtering out unnecessary values

```
k2 = [ y  for x,y in list(zip(l,m)) if x>0]
k2
>>>[10, 20]
```